# How to get ascii code of a character in a string column in python polars dataframe?

Tags: python

I'd like to get the ascii code of a character in a column in python polars dataframe.

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'a' : ['apple', 'banana']})
df.select('a').with_columns(pl.col('a').str.slice(0, 1))
```

Slicing works fine, but how do I apply ord() function to it?
Ord() works fine in pure python, like:

```
print((df['a'][0], ord(df['a'][0][0:1])))
# ('apple', 97)
```

Comment: How about `df.select(pl.col("a").apply(lambda s: ord(s[0])))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Keeping as much of your code unchanged as possible, you can add to the end of your expressions such that

```
df.select('a').with_columns(pl.col('a').str.slice(0, 1)).map_rows(lambda x: ord(x[0]))
```